# Get the class of the first DIV from inside HTML

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="first">
 <div class="second">

   etc
 </dv>
</div>
```

How can I get the class of the first div ? ("first") using jQuery ?

I have this html inside a variable "$body_html"

Comment: I think we need a little more information. What's the parent of .first?  Are there other classes with first? Or are you just looking to see if it has first?

Comment: If you have the html in a variable then use that variable as your primary jQuery selector and add ' div:first' to the selector to search within your variable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Leah. Unfortunately, I don't know in what way exactly you are going to get this class. But I suppose, that the next ideas can help you. If you know the second class you may use the next code

```
    $('.second').closest('div').attr('class');
```

If you don't, you may add the id to the first div tag and then use

```
    $('#divid').attr('class')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div:first").attr("class")
```

That'll do it for you.

Comment: lol first version does not work XD had to frantically edit it XD

Comment: $("div:first").className  works, or $("div:first").attr("class") but you can't mix the two as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it eg. like that:

```
var element = jQuery('div:first');
alert(element.attr('class'));
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Gb6/2/) for a proof.

Answer (score 0):

```
$($body_html + ' div:first').attr('class');
```

This finds the first div within the variable with your html markup and gets its class attribute.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YSdCX/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var classString=$("div:first").attr("class")
var classArray= classString.split(" ");
```

Since Element you are looking for may have **multiple css-classes**, with above code you can get an array of css-classes an element is having.

If you just want to check whether an element is having particular class do as below

```
var boolResult= $("div:first").hasClass('classToTest');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var thisClass = $("div:first").attr("class");
```

Will get the class attribute of the first `<div>` using the `:first` selector. See [here for its use.](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Alternatively you may be best selecting the `<div>` by `id` if your markup does change.

Also `attr(attribute)` can be used to get any attribute present on an element so can be useful for getting `id` attributes and so on.

Comment: Why the down votes? It works and does what the poster wanted.